# Hibernate annotations one-to-many

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I can't add any records to my WorkOrder table. It adds records to Company table and Handyman table. Probably something wrong with my annotations. Is there any mistakes?
I have 3 tables.
1 Company table, contains names of companies, addresses, phone numbers, etc.
2 Handyman table, handyman name, address, hourly rate, etc.
3 WorkOrders, work order number, job site address,

Tables Company and WorkOrders  are linked through a foreign key in one-to-many association
Tables Handyman and WorkOrders  are linked through a foreign key in one-to-many association

WorkOrder.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Work_orders", schema="handyman")
public class WorkOrder implements Serializable {

// id, Work_order, Address, Email, Comment, Date_received, Price, 
Companys_list_id, Handymans_list_id

@ManyToOne  
@JoinColumn(name="Companys_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Company company;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@JoinColumn(name="Handymans_list_id", referencedColumnName="id")
private Handyman handyman;
```

Company.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Companys_list", schema="handyman")
public class Company implements Serializable {

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Companys_list_id")
private Set<WorkOrder> workOrders;
```

Handyman.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="Handymans_list_id")
private Set<WorkOrder> workOrders;
```

Here's my JSP file:

```
<s:form action="saveWorkOrder">

        <s:actionerror/>
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.workOrder"      label="Work order number" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.address"        label="Adress/Location" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.email"          label="Email" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.comment"        label="Comment" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.dateReceived"   label="Date receved" />
        <s:textfield name="workOrder.price"          label="Price" />
        <s:textfield name="company.companyName"      label="Company name" />
        <s:textfield name="handyman.handymanName"     label="Handyman name" />
        <s:submit value="Register" />

    </s:form>
```

WorkOrderManagment.java

```
public String saveWorkOrder(WorkOrder workOrder) throws Exception
{

    System.out.println("Saving work order...");
    WorkOrderDaoHibernate dao = new WorkOrderDaoHibernate();
    workOrder = dao.saveWorkOrder(workOrder);
    return SUCCESS;

}
```

WorkOrderDaoHibernate.java

```
public WorkOrder saveWorkOrder(WorkOrder workOrder)
{
    SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session =  sf.openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();
    Integer id = (Integer) session.save(workOrder);
    trans.commit();
    workOrder.setId(id);
    session.close();
    return workOrder;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the company and handyman pojos define one to many relationship with workorder and also has cascade set to all, a better solution would be to:
1. Create an object of company, set values and collection of workorder objects
2. Create an object of handyman, set values and collection of workorder objects
3. Open session and save 1 and 2 in single batch.